# JS not accepting <> greater than or less than signs

Tags: jquery, regex, parsing, drupal

I've been stuck on an interesting (IE: mind numbing) question for the past few hours.

I've been trying to parse operators with regex:

```
([<>]=?|[!=]=)
```

The ones that I want are: `<= >= < > == !=`

`==` and `!=` matches great. But all the ones having to do with `<` or `>` doesn't on my Drupal site, even though they should theoretically work.

What I ended up doing is this: `.replace(/more than/ig, ">")`

And in the text write "`more than`" where I would write `>`, and it works! Matches perfectly and everything...

This is really really silly, but I cannot think of a reason why this issue would exist. I turned off all the filters in Drupal, and in Firebug just writing `>` normally looks like `>`, not escaped or anything.

I'm really confused and hope for enlightenment.

Thanks.

Comment: what are you parsing against?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could something be changing your source material into entities?

```
&gt; vs > 

&lt; vs <
```

Comment: Well, not exactly but it conveys the same idea.  I was just showing one in code mode and one without to demonstrate that they looked the same.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try actually matching the escaped version?

Firebug will not show the content escaped, i.e. it will not display `>` as entities (`&gt;`) even though they are (view the source of this page to check that). It seems very likely that it is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
((&lt;|&gt;)=?|[!=]=)
```